# Does thermal equilibration affect compression work for an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, work, ideal-gas

Consider compression of an ideal gas that is uniform in pressure but *nonuniform in temperature*, from volume $V_1$ to $V_2$. For simplicity of the problem let's say the gas is divided into 2 regions $A$ and $B$ of equal uniform pressure but *unequal* uniform temperature. The compression is externally adiabatic (no heat transfer to the environment), but internal heat transfer between $A$ and $B$ may occur.

Consider three cases of the compression process:

1. Compression of the gas without internal heat transfer between the two regions $A$ and $B$.
2. Compression after $A$ and $B$ thermally equilibrate.
3. Compression while $A$ and $B$ are thermally equilibrating, and the final temperature is uniform.

Known values: $V_1$, $V_{1A}$, $T_{1A}$, $T_{1B}$, $V_2$, $c_v$, $R$

We want to find the work transfer for each of the compression processes. My attempt is below.

---

### Case 1: No thermal mixing.

Differential first law yields

$$ d(m_A c_v T_A + m_B c_v T_B) = -Pd(V_A + V_B)$$

$$ d(\frac{PV_A + PV_B}{\gamma - 1}) = -Pd(V_A + V_B)$$

$$ d(\frac{PV_A + PV_B}{\gamma - 1}) = -Pd(V_A + V_B)$$

$$ \gamma \frac{d(V_A + V_B)}{V_A + V_B} + \frac{dP}{P} = 0$$

$$ P(V_A + V_B)^{\gamma} = constant$$

This is the usual isentropic relation between $P$ and $V$, which is unaffected by different temperatures of the 2 regions. The work is simply the usual isentropic work, which is also unaffected by the temperature distribution:

$$ W = \int_1^2{PdV}$$

$$ W = \int_1^2{P_1V_1^{\gamma}\frac{dV}{V^{\gamma}}}$$

$$ W = \frac{P_1 V_1 ^{\gamma}}{1-\gamma} (V_2^{1-\gamma} - V_1^{1-\gamma})$$

### Case 2: Compression after thermal mixing.

First law for the thermal equilibration yields a final temperature $T$:

$$ m_A c_v (T - T_{1A}) + m_B c_v (T-T_{1B}) = 0$$

$$ T = \frac{m_A c_v T_{1A} + m_B c_v T_{1B}}{m_A c_v + m_B c_v}$$

$$ T = \frac{m_A T_{1A} + m_B T_{1B}}{m_A  + m_B }$$

First law for the comression yields

$$ m c_v dT = -PdV$$

$$ d(\frac{PV}{\gamma-1}) = -PdV$$

$$ d(\frac{PV}{\gamma-1}) = -PdV$$

$$ P(V_A + V_B)^{\gamma} = constant$$

This is the same $(P,V)$ relation as Case 1, therefore the work should be the same *if the pressure $P=P_1$ after thermal equilibration*, which I think it is?

### Case 3: Compression during thermal mixing.

The 2 gas regions are thermally equilibrating during the compression. The differential first law yields

$$ d(m_A c_v T_A + m_B c_v T_B) = -Pd(V_A + V_B)$$

$$ d(\frac{PV_A + PV_B}{\gamma - 1}) = -Pd(V_A + V_B)$$

This is essentially unchanged from Case 1, so again we have

$$ P(V_A + V_B)^{\gamma} = constant$$

thus the compression work must be the same again.

---

To conclude, I found that the compression work in each case is unchanged by thermal equilibration of regions in the ideal gas. However, Cases 2 and 3 are irreversible since entropy is generated during thermal mixing, but Case 1 is reversible.

**Why doesn't irreversibility of thermal mixing influence the work required to compress a gas?**

Comment: Need some clarifications. How are gases A and B divided? I'm envisioning a cylinder with a thin (essentially zero volume) movable barrier between A and B positioned initially so that the volumes of A and B are equal and the total volume are the V1 and V2 of the problem. Adjacent to one of the gases (A or B) is an insulated piston which will be doing the compression. Then for Case 1 the barrier between the gases is insulated, allowing no heat transfer between the gases.

Comment: Now, for Case 2 it seems that the barrier is initially insulated and stays that way until the end of the compression, at which time it is replace by a conductive barrier to allow thermal equilibrium after the compression. Alternatively, the compression can take place so rapidly that it is adiabatic.

Comment: Finally, for Case 3 there is initially an insulating barrier so the temperatures are different. But it is replaced with a conducting barrier at the start of the compression to allow heat transfer to occur between the gases. And the process is carried out slowly.  Is this what is going on?

Comment: @BobD That is correct.